# Способы хранения данных в С++

Tags: c++, база-данных, хранение-данных

На каникулы задали лабораторную работу (сделать программу, которая будет хранить метаданные файла, и текст содержащийся в нем, и различные функции для изменения данных), где одна из функций программ, это хранение данных, но обычное сохранение данных в `txt` файле не хочется делать. Как можно сохранять/хранить данные в другом формате?

Comment: Гугл - `c++ serialize` https://habr.com/post/244963/

Comment: Можно использовать xml или json, если у вас данные, которые нельзя представить в текстовом формате (например стмвол '\0' не может быть представлен в текстовом файле), то их следует перекодировать с помощью base64.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, в текстовом файле могут быть представлены любые символы.

Comment: @Qwertiy я уверен, вы прекрастно поняли что имелось ввиду

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, нет, я понял, что эта фраза может иметь более-менее правильную интерпретацию, да и то с натяжкой, а люди любят говорить всякую муть про текстовые файлы. И даже если я что-то понял, это не означает, что автор вопроса понял так же.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, вообще-то, лично я не вижу причин использовать base64 при записи в файл. И встроенных функция в плюсах вроде нет (или есть?), и кодирование выполнять сложно, и объём увеличивается значительно. Есть куча более удобных способов для более-менее текстовой информации. И то, всё это относится не к невозможности записать в файл, а к последующему парсингу этого файла, а он вообще будет зависеть не от способа кодирования, а от выбранного представления формата.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87871/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-andrej-levkovitch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще xml или json, как уже написали. Как вариант БД можно использовать sqlite. Очень проста в использовании и не требует дополнительной установки на компьютер. Достаточно положить [sqlite-dll-win64-x64-3260000.zip](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) библиотеки из архива рядом с базой. Удобный и бесплатный инструмент редактирования [SQLiteManager](https://www.sqlabs.com/sqlitemanager.php).

Пример использования json могу дать такой(я использую Qt тут): 
сам json:

```
{
    "Format": [
        {
            "dateFormat": "MM.yyyy"
        },
        {
            "dateFormat": "yyyy.MM"
        },
        {
            "dateFormat": "dd.MM.yyyy"
        }
   ]
}
```

В функцию чтения передаётся путь до файла:

```
...
QFileInfo info(QDir::currentPath()+"formatDate.json");
ReadJSON(QFileInfo info)
...
```

Функция чтения :

```
   void MW::ReadJSON(QFileInfo info) {
         if (info.fileName()=="formatDate.json") {
            QString SettingsPath = info.absoluteFilePath();
            QFile loadFile(SettingsPath);
            if (!loadFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
                QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Ошибка"), tr("Нельзя открыть файл!"));
                return;
            } else {
                QByteArray SettingsData = loadFile.readAll();
                QJsonDocument loadDoc(QJsonDocument::fromJson(SettingsData));

                QJsonArray jsonArray = loadDoc["Format"].toArray();            
                foreach (const QJsonValue & value, jsonArray) {
                    QJsonObject obj = value.toObject();
                    qDebug()<<obj["dateFormat"].toString();
                }
             }
          }

    }
```

Функция записи файла:

```
   void MW::SaveJSON() {
        QString PathToSettingsFiles = "formatDate.json";
        QFileInfo fi(QDir::currentPath(), PathToSettingsFiles);
        QFile JsonFile(fi.absoluteFilePath());
        JsonFile.open(QFile::WriteOnly);
        QJsonDocument JsonDoc;
        QJsonArray dateFormat_array;
        QString dateFormat_str("dateFormat");
        QStringList DateList = { "MM.yyyy", "yyyy.MM", "dd.MM.yyyy" };
        for (int x=0; x<DateList.size(); x++) {
            QJsonObject item_data;
            item_data.insert(dateFormat_str, QJsonValue(DateList.at(x)));
            dateFormat_array.push_back(QJsonValue(item_data));
        }
        QJsonObject final_object;
        final_object.insert(QString("Format"), QJsonValue(dateFormat_array));
        JsonDoc.setObject(final_object);
        JsonFile.write(JsonDoc.toJson());
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!